# const source = { uri: audioUrl } can't find my local file

Tags: react-native, expo-av

I use expo-av and want to use this:

`const source = { uri: audioUrl }`

When I try to add network URL, it works, but it can't find my local file.

// Don't work

```
{ uri: "./assets/040.wav" }
```

// Work

```
const source = { uri:"https://carolinegabriel.com/demo/jskeyboard/sounds/042.wav" }
```

// Work

```
require(`./assets/040.wav`)
```